# Find missing days and grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, datetime

I have a dataframe that looks something like this

```
            dt user  
0   2016-01-01    a    
1   2016-01-02    a   
2   2016-01-03    a    
3   2016-01-04    a    
4   2016-01-05    a    
5   2016-01-06    a    
6   2016-01-01    b    
7   2016-01-02    b    
8   2016-01-03    b    
9   2016-01-04    b    
10  2016-01-05    b    
11  2016-01-06    b    
12  2016-01-07    b 
13  2015-12-31    c    
14   2016-01-01   c    
15   2016-01-02   c    
16   2016-01-03   c    
17   2016-01-04   c    
18  2016-01-05    c    
19  2016-01-06    c    
20  2016-01-07    c 
21  2016-01-08    c    
22  2016-01-09    c
23  2016-01-10    c
```

I want to find the missing dates for each user. For the date ranges,  the minimum date is `2015-12-31`  and the maximum date is `2016-01-10`. The result would look like this:

```
   user     missing_days
    a          5
    b          4
    c          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `isin` to check the date range against each group of `user` and `agg.sum` the returned boolean mask of each group

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt']) #if `dt` columns already in datetime dtype, ignore this
check_dates = pd.date_range('2015-12-31', '2016-01-10', freq='D')
s =  df.groupby('user').dt.agg(lambda x: (~check_dates.isin(x)).sum())

Out[920]:
user
a    5
b    4
c    0
Name: dt, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
### Convert your dates to datetime
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'], infer_datetime_format=True)
### Create the list of dates per user
user_days = df.groupby('user')['dt'].apply(list)

### Initialize the final dataframe
df_miss_dates = pd.DataFrame(user_days)

all_dates = pd.date_range('2015-12-31', '2016-01-10', freq='D')
### Find the number of missing dates per user
df_miss_dates['missing_days'] = df_miss_dates['dt'].apply(lambda x: len(set(all_dates) - set(x)))
df_miss_dates.drop(columns='dt', inplace=True)
print(df_miss_dates)
```

Output:

```py
      missing_days
user              
a                5
b                4
c                0
```

Comment: Looks more elegant than my answer +1

Comment: it returns an empty dataframe when there are no missing days. Can u please modify it to put 0 where there are no missing days instead of returning an empty dataframe?

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just ran my code again with your updated dataframe and it does still give your intended output

Comment: mistake on my part. Apologies

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
from datetime import date, timedelta
sdate = date(2015, 12, 31)   # start date
edate = date(2016, 1, 10)   # end date
delta = edate - sdate       # as timedelta
days=[]
for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    day = sdate + timedelta(days=i)
    days.append(str(day))
user=[]
missing_days = []
for user_n in df.user.unique():
    user_days = df.loc[df.user ==user_n,'dt' ].to_list()
    md = len([day for day in days if day not in user_days])
    user.append(user_n)
    missing_days.append(md)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'user': user,'missing_days': missing_days})
new_df
```

**output**

```
user    missing_days
a       5
b       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Define the following function:

```
def missingDates(grp : pd.Series, d1 : pd.Timestamp, d2 : pd.Timestamp):
    ndTotal = (d2 - d1).days + 1
    ndPresent = grp[grp.between(d1, d2)].index.size
    return ndTotal - ndPresent
```

Then apply it to each group and change into a DataFrame (as I see
from your post, you want just a **DataFrame**, with 2 columns):

```
result = df.groupby('user')['dt'].apply(missingDates,
    pd.to_datetime('2015-12-31'), pd.to_datetime('2016-01-10'))\
    .rename('missing_days').reset_index()
```

The result is:

```
  user  missing_days
0    a             5
1    b             4
2    c             0
```

My solution relies on the fact that dates within each group are unique
and all dates are without the time part. If these conditions were not
met, there should be added dates normalization and invoking of *unique*
function.

Additional remark: Change *dt* (the column name) to some other name,
because *dt* is the name of *date accessor* in *Pandas*.
It is a bad practice to "cover" standard *pandasonic* names with e.g.
either column or variable names.